# How to fix InstallShield error -1501: Could not compress?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installshield

I'm using an InstallShield project to generate setup files. Everything was working fine, but I've recently encountered following error which says,

- Could not compress "bin\x86\QA\AppManifest.xaml" into "\Default
  Configuration\MSI
- Could not find file
  "bin\x86\QA\AppManifest.xaml"    ISDEV : error : -6103:

So far I have been unable to fix these issues. Can someone help me understand what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Thought it's late to reply, I came with similar error on dynamic file linking. But, problem was with double slash being on Resource directory.

My problem was, I provided path as : "PATH_TO_HELP_FILES\Docs\", while i removed the last \ on path i.e PATH_TO_HELP_FILES\Docs, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

- It could be the **AppManifest.xaml** is missing from the source folder? I think this is the most likely scenario - your application build could have failed, and this particular file could be missing?
- You could also have a **file lock** in the build output folder - did you try to reboot and rebuild?
- You can also try to run the **release wizard** and make a new release configuration and try to build that

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/192738/What-is-AppManifest-xaml-in-Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

Another late reply.  For my situation, I merged multiple branches together, and something is lost along the way.  It was probably a setting file or something with the gitignore file.  Anyways, I got that same -1501 could not compress file error.   The reason was the build order of projects in the solution.  Incorrect build order caused VS to look for dependencies when they were not yet created or included.  I right-clicked on the solution, went to the Dependencies tab to set the order (by setting dependencies).  Once that was done, I could Clean Solution and Rebuild Solution without getting any error.